# How to set clause between two fields in RavenDb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ravendb, raven, ravendb4

I try to

```
var result = await _session.Query<NewScreenerDto>()
    .Where(p => p.PSAR > p.PrevPSAR, true)
    .ToListAsync();
```

but I get this error message.

> "Could not understand expression: Convert(from NewScreenerDtos,
> IRavenQueryable`1).Where(p => (p.PSAR > p.PrevPSAR), True)"

Does it mean that RavenDB cannot translate this simple query?

Comment: What is the usage of the **true** parameter as a second parameter to the Where clause? 
Did you mean `Where(p => p.PSAR > p.PrevPSAR)`

Comment: @Danielle I don't know. That was require and i tested either true and false. That description was 'exact' and i didn't deep on that.

Comment: can you run the query w/o the 'true'  ?
just use `Where(p => p.PSAR > p.PrevPSAR)` ?

Comment: @Danielle no. This is required